# Finding the coordinates x y z of the center of a surface

Tags: ruby, math, 3d, surface, centroid

I have a surface in a 3D space, and I need to calculate the coordinates of the center of that surface. The surface is a polygon.

I found this formula:

```
X1 += SUM[(xi  + xi+1 ) * (xi* yi+1  - xi+1 * yi )]/6/area 
Y1 += SUM[(yi  + yi+1) * (xi* yi+1  - xi+1 * yi )]/6/area
```

But it only works for 2D. It gives x and y values.  In my case I need 3 coordinates, x y z.

How can I do that ?

I need the center of the surfaces selected, but they may have any shape as they are a polygon.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Is the polygon warped out of the plane?  The answer you get will depend on that.

Comment: yes it not on the xy plane , the polygon is in between xyz, when i find the center point manually all coordinates are different from 0.

Comment: Do you mean a center of mass location?  You have to do an integration.  Do you know calculus?

Comment: yes but i don't have a solid object in 3d but just a surface like it's not a cube but a rectangle and i need to find its center point, i don't know if i need to do integration as i'm more of a programmer than a mathematician.

Comment: You certainly can think of it as a solid object: It's a 3D thin shell, common in structural and mechanical engineering.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to prove that the centroid of the projection of a polygon on any plane is the projection of the centroid of that polygon on that plane.

So just calculate the centroid of the projections of the polygon on x-y plane and y-z plane, and you'll get the coordinate of the centroid of that polygon.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Point = Struct.new(:x, :y, :z)

def centroid(vertices, dimensions: [:x, :y])
  area = 0
  centroid_x, centroid_y = 0, 0
  vertices.count.times do |i|
    v1, v2 = vertices[i, 2]
    v2 ||= vertices[0]
    x1, y1 = dimensions.map{|d| v1.send(d)}
    x2, y2 = dimensions.map{|d| v2.send(d)}
    a = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
    area += a
    centroid_x += (x1 + x2) * a
    centroid_y += (y1 + y2) * a
  end

  area *= 0.5
  centroid_x /= (6.0 * area)
  centroid_y /= (6.0 * area)
  [centroid_x, centroid_y]
end

vertices = [
  Point.new(1, 0, 0),
  Point.new(0, 2, 0),
  Point.new(0, 0, 3)
]

p centroid(vertices, dimensions: [:x, :y])
p centroid(vertices, dimensions: [:y, :z])
p centroid(vertices, dimensions: [:z, :x])
```

prints

```
[0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666]
[0.6666666666666666, 1.0]
[1.0, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aetherus it didn't work for my example:

```
X1 = 0
Y1 = 0
Y11 = 0
Z1 = 0

for i in 0..d.vertices.size-2           
  X1 += (d.vertices[i].position[0] + d.vertices[i+1].position[0]) * (d.vertices[i].position[0] * d.vertices[i+1].position[1] - d.vertices[i+1].position[0] * d.vertices[i].position[1])

  Y1 += (d.vertices[i].position[1] + d.vertices[i+1].position[1]) * (d.vertices[i].position[0] * d.vertices[i+1].position[1] - d.vertices[i+1].position[0] * d.vertices[i].position[1])             

  Y11 += (d.vertices[i].position[1] + d.vertices[i+1].position[1]) * (d.vertices[i].position[1] * d.vertices[i+1].position[2] - d.vertices[i+1].position[1] * d.vertices[i].position[2])         

  Z1 += (d.vertices[i].position[2] + d.vertices[i+1].position[2]) * (d.vertices[i].position[1] * d.vertices[i+1].position[2] - d.vertices[i+1].position[1] * d.vertices[i].position[2])
end             

x=X1/(6.0*(d.area))             
y=Y1/(6.0*(d.area))
y1=Y11/(6.0*(d.area))           
z=Z1/(6.0*(d.area))

UI.messagebox("x1 #{x} Y1 #{y} \n y11 #{y1} z1 #{z}")
```

With "d" is my polygon the xy is for x-y projection and y1z for y-z projection.

Comment: I reformatted your code. I think the problem is in your `0..d.vertices.size-2` part, which should be `0..(d.vertices.size-1)` (I don't know which one of `..` and `-` has higher priority) or `0...d.vertices.size` because you need to loop over every edge.

Comment: You should not use capitalized words as variable names. In Ruby, capitalized identifiers are for constants.

Comment: And you should not divide your `X1` by 6 times the polygon area. You should divide them by 6 times **the area of the projection on the xy plain**. Same for `Y1`, `Y11` and `Z1`.

Comment: @Aetherus thnx a lot for your answers i'll try them, also i found that in order to have the center of a polygon you can use the sum of vertices xi,yi,zi and divide each one by the number of vertices. and it'll get you the cx,cy,cz coordinates of the center. do you have any idea about this option and is it applicable for every shape of polygon ?

Comment: It depends on how you define **center**. My solution gives the **centroid** (a.k.a. center of mass), the point whose coordinate is the mean value of **all points in the polygon**. Your suggestion gives the mean value of **all the vertices**.